# Optional() in my text view

Tags: xcode, swift

For one of my static labels on my main story board, it prints out "Optional("United States"). However, I would like it to print out "United States". So my question is, how do I get rid of the "Optional" part? I've already tried doing:

```
if let p = placemarks!.first{
      self.addressLabel.text = "\(p.country)"
}
```

I think the exclamation mark is supposed to "unwrap" some value right? However, even if I do `p = placemarks!.first`, it prints out "Optional("United States").

Below is the rest of my code just in case you would like some context:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Map Demo Rob 2
//
//  Created by Jae Hyun Kim on 8/17/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Jae Hyun Kim. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var latitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var courseLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speedLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var altitudeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var addressLabel: UILabel!
    var manager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)

        let userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
        self.latitudeLabel.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
        self.longitudeLabel.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
        self.courseLabel.text = "\(userLocation.course)"
        self.speedLabel.text = "\(userLocation.speed)"
        self.altitudeLabel.text = "\(userLocation.altitude)"

        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
            print(userLocation)

            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }
            else {
                if let p = placemarks?.first{
                    self.addressLabel.text = "\(p.country)"
                }
            }
        })




    }

}
```

Comment: p.country is optional, you would need to unwrap that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
if let p = placemarks!.first{
    self.addressLabel.text = "\(p.country)"
}
```

`p.country` is an `Optional<String>`. You need to unwrap that aswell in order to output only it's content (if it exists).

```
if let country = placemarks?.first?.country {
    self.addressLabel.text = country
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for your response. Could you please explain what is happening in this statement: `placemarks?.first?.country`? What does placemarks actually stand for? And first? And country? I'm sorry for such noob questions... And why do we need those optionals there? I have a basic understanding of what optionals are, that is, they are variables that can hold only two types of values. A value of the specified type and a nil. Thank you in advance...

Comment: And what does the periods mean in this context? I think it means calling some method correct? What does it mean in this context? I apologize for such disorganized questioning.

Comment: If you option-click on a variable, Xcode will show you its definition and documentation (if it exists).  My guess is `placemarks` is an array of objects, and `.first` returns the first object in the array.